# I need to simplify a geopackage with the coasts of Italy in QGIS

Tags: qgis

On the top the coast with the geopackage without modification ([I uploaded here the file](https://mega.nz/file/LTpU1QQT#vz71cdhoW33Dvp27y0HwWqAUp5t0DoY3DU07UM0PUSU)), on the bottom the coast after passing the "Simplify" function (method: Douglas-Peucker distance, tolerance 1). Please note how the islands are far too simplified, while the coastline is often acceptable. How can I solve this?

[image: Original]
[image: Simplified]

I am using QGIS 3.28.3.

*I could not do a proper image resize here on Stack, I have never done it.*

Comment: Play with the tolerance and try also the Visvalingam method. The makes sometimes prettier result.

Comment: Notice that because EPSG:4258 is using degrees as units, the tolerance of 1 means 1 degree, that corresponds to about 110 kilometers at the latitude of Italy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using QGIS (3.28.3) Simplify at **0.0005** (as your using WGS84)

Result does not collapse the islands.[image]

Comment: Great, everything worked. Thank you!